# How to process a very fast stream of data using Flow in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, channel

I have a callback that is called very fast like 100 times in a second or maybe sometimes more. I have converted this callback into a flow using [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html).

```kotlin
/**
 * The responsibility of [ParameterAccessFlow] is to add [ParameterAccessMetadata] provided to it
 * via the [relay] to the [flow] that it exposes via [flow]
 */
open class ParameterAccessFlow {

  private val _flow = createCallbackFlow()

  /** The flow that consumers can use to collect [ParameterAccessMetadata] for Parameter access */
  open val flow: Flow<ParameterAccessMetadata> = _flow

  private val noOPListener: ParameterAccessListener =
      object : ParameterAccessListener {
        override fun onParameterAccessed(parameterAccessMetadata: ParameterAccessMetadata) {
          //Some warning code if we are not ready
        }
      }
  private var parameterAccessListener: ParameterAccessListener = noOPListener

  /** Relay this Metadata to the flow */
  open fun relay(metadata: ParameterAccessMetadata) {
    parameterAccessListener.onParameterAccessed(metadata)
  }

  /** Create the actual callbackFlow **/
  fun createCallbackFlow() = callbackFlow {
    val parameterAccessListener: ParameterAccessListener =
        object : ParameterAccessListener {
          override fun onParameterAccessed(parameterAccessMetadata: ParameterAccessMetadata) {
            val channelResult = trySend(parameterAccessMetadata)
            if (channelResult.isFailure) {
              //We could not send to the flow. Maybe buffer is full/Channel closed. Log this
            }
          }
        }

    this@ParameterAccessFlow.parameterAccessListener = parameterAccessListener
    awaitClose { this@ParameterAccessFlow.parameterAccessListener = noOPListener }
  }
}
```

Now at the consumer end this is how I am consuming it

```kotlin
/** This is where we are collecting from the flow and providing it to the aggregators */
  open suspend fun collect() {
    parameterAccessFlow.flow
        // Adding a buffer with a capacity as the producer here is faster than consumer
        .buffer(capacity = BUFFER_CAPACITY, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
        .collect {
          withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { 
            parameterAccessListenerAggregator.onParameterAccessed(it) 
          }
        }
  }
```

Couple of questions on this approach

1. Is this the best way to consume from a callback based API for consumption ? I always want to consumer in a non UI thread.
2. In this case the producer is producing faster than the consumer can consume so I am adding the buffer as the default buffer of size 64 is leading to a failure when I send using trySend. I don't want to miss any logs. I did not add UNLIMITED capacity as there are some posts against not using them from Jake Wharton :D can I do better here
3. All log processing is independent is there a way I can make this process paralell to speed up the consumer ?
4. For a CPU intensive consumption(some processing on the log and adding them to storage) shall I use Dispatchers.Default or Dispatchers.IO the only downside that I see for Default is that the threads are limited by the CPU core hence the consumption might be slow
5. Would it be better if I batch process them. Like processing 100 logs each time with dispatch vs 10 times batch of 10 logs in terms of processing time and thread switching overhead.

Thanks for going through this long post :)

Comment: There are only three choices for how you deal with producing data at a high rate: buffer, drop, or speed up your consumer.  You will absolutely have to pick one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @LouisWasserman I don't want to drop for sure. Among the other two, I am first trying to speed up the consumer and then add a buffer with a specific capacity.

Comment: If your buffer fills up, then you will need a bigger buffer, perhaps an unlimited one.  That has disadvantages, yes, but there may not be an alternative.